# Can't set breakpoints in some places of Android SDK source (Eclipse)

Tags: android, debugging

I can't put breakpoints in private or package access methods of the Android SDK, or classes. I can put them in public or protected. Why? And if possible, how do I change that?

More exactly, the not working case is that a breakpoint is added to the class signature and it says "class: classname". But the debugger never stops in this class.

It doesn't work in certain classes at all, also not in public methods... for example Gallery class. But it works other class, for example AnalogClock (which is in the same package as Gallery). Or View.

Answer (score 0):

one reason that you can not set breakpoint is that the Android sdk class do not contains the implements details.

you can use Java Decompiler to open the /(sdk path)/platforms/android-xx/android.jar file to see the sdk class detail, and you will find the implements of all methods are like these:

```
  public int getVerticalScrollbarWidth()
  {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
  }
```

and do not contains the private methods.
so the eclipse java debugger do not know how to set the breakpoint, because the attach source do not correspond exactly to sdk class.

i have a not so good way to deal with this problem.
1.copy the source file(e.g. /android/view/View.java) to any android/java project in eclipse.
2.set the breakpoint in the file in step 1.
3.now you can hit the breakpoint.